# How Blazor manage user Session?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

new to Blazor I'm not sure to understand how user session is working.

I'm trying to do a web site with Blazor Server Hosting (.NET Core 3.1).
I have a service to Store a Customer like this :

```
 public class AppData
    {   
        public Customer CurrentCustomer { get; set; }

        public AppData()
        {         
            this.CurrentCustomer = new Customer() { IsWebConnected = false };
        }
    }
```

On Startup.cs I add :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            AppData data = new AppData();
            services.AddSingleton<Service.AppData>(data);
}
```

What does it mean ? 
When a CurrentCustomer is set (with a login page for exemple), I can access it with relative data on different pages when I launch on a browser. 
But when I launch another browser on my pc, I cab see the same user set (with same vaues). It seems to be shared.

I have been working on old ASP.NET Webform and I'm trying to do the same things than Session (One session by user), but is it the same way with Blazor ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AppData data = new AppData();
services.AddSingleton<Service.AppData>(data);
```

This adds a Singleton instance. And yes, that is shared between all users. Cookies are not involved. This behaves like the `Application[]` object in WebForms.

`Session[]` has no direct counterpart, but there are many solutions. The docs [list them here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Note that you should try to be as 'stateless' as possible, so consider fetching your data from the Db every time the page Initializes.